# Reference for Iwahori-Hecke algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-groups

I recently came across the notion of an Iwahori-Hecke algebra. I would like to learn the basics about this type of algebras (mainly to get an intuition about them, as they seem to be related to some objects I am working with, having a list of applications would also be good). Could you recommend me a reference? I would prefer something not too long (even if it is harder to read) as I usually don't feel like reading super long textbooks is that useful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is an exposition in Humphreys "Reflection groups and Coxeter groups"

Comment: It depends on for what purpose you need Iwahori-Hecke algebras.  Is it (according to your tags) for representation theory of p-adic groups ?